# problems taking the value of the select option jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp

I need to take the value of the select option to send it to another page to be processed, but can not capture the value.
any ideas?
the select is loaded from the database, that part works, shows the categories of product.

```
<%@page import="com.sun.xml.internal.txw2.Document"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>


<%@ page import = "com.seminario.beans.categoria" %>
<%@ page import = "com.seminario.datos.DbCategoria" %>
<%@ page import = "com.seminario.beans.Producto" %>
<%@ page import = "com.seminario.datos.DbProducto" %>

<jsp:useBean id="dataProd" class="com.seminario.datos.DbProducto" scope="page"/>
<jsp:setProperty name="dataProd" property="*"/>


<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="../stylo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Alta Producto</title>

    </head> 

    <%

    categoria c = new categoria();
    DbCategoria bdc = new DbCategoria();
    ArrayList <categoria> myList = new ArrayList();
    myList = bdc.SelectAll();

    %>   
    <body>        
        <h1>Nuevo Producto</h1>
        <form name ='formulario' action='nuevoProducto.jsp' method='post' >
        Descripcion<input name='descripcion' type='text' size='20' required><br>
        Precio<input name='precio' type='text' size='20' required><br>
        Stock<input name='stock' type='text' size='20' required><br>

  **Categoria <select name="categoid" id="categoid">
        <% for(int i=0;i<myList.size();i++){%>
        <option value="<%= myList.get(i).getId() %>"  > <%out.print(myList.get(i).getDescripcion());%></option>
        <%}%>
        </select><br>** 


        Imagen<input name="imagen"  text="seleccionar archivo" type="file" size="10" accept="image/jpg" /><br>



         <input type ="submit"  value ='Guardar' />
         <!--  <input type="submit" value="guardar">-->
                </form>

        <br><br><a  href='menuAdmin.jsp'>Volver al menu principal</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: how do you send your value to another page

Comment: what do you mean by you can not capture the value? is `request.getParameter("categoid")` empty?

Comment: I send the value with the submit button in a bean.

Comment: I think request.getParameter("categoid") is null ,

Comment: <option value="<%= myList.get(i).getId() %>"  > <%out.print(myList.get(i).getDescripcion());%></option>   this code is correct ?

Comment: the code seems fine but you do not send the value to a bean, you are sending it to `nuevoProducto.jsp`.

Comment: true , sorry , i send the value to nuevoProducto.jsp but its not getting the value i dont know why !

Comment: use `<% out.print(myList.get(i).getId()) %>` insteand of `<%= myList.get(i).getId() %>`

Comment: i tried <% out.print(myList.get(i).getId()) %> but did not work